# Q: How do I link a Chrome Web Store Group Publisher Account to a Google Payments Merchant Center account?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, chrome-web-store

We've built a Chrome Extension and published it through a group publishing account (so multiple people on the team could edit the app on the Chrome Store).

We're now getting ready to charge for it, but when I go to link the publisher to a  Google Payments Merchant Center account to receive payments, I eventually get a message saying "**Uh oh, something went wrong**" when hitting the submit button.

Does anyone have any experience here?

Comment: Check this [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/money) if you properly follow the instruction here. This documentation explains you on how to Register for a Google Checkout Merchant account. It also includes the topic In-app payments, One-time charge, Subscription and Offering a limited trial version of your item. `Note that Chrome Web Store payment methods are not available for hosted apps.` For more info check this [thread](https://support.google.com/payments/merchant/answer/7161426?hl=en-GB).

Comment: Thanks @KENdi the docs are great, and I believe I've followed them, but still no luck - I'm going to go with either there's some bug that needs to be fixed by Google, or it's not possible for a group publishing account to link to a google payments account.  The **"Uh oh"*** message I'm getting isn't helping me solve this issue of course :)  -- and, I'm having a real hard time getting in touch with anyone in the chrome store dept at Google